# How to set svn ignore property in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive, svnignore

I want to add the SVN ignore property to my project to ignore **target** folder and **.classpath**.

So I went through team → set property, but I didn't know how the configuration for the name and values would be. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `svn:ignore` using *Team* → *Add to svn:ignore* on the right click of file. However, if the file is already committed to SVN this option will not be enabled.

You would need to remove it from SVN, clean up the local repository and then add `svn:ignore`.

Comment: What do you mean by project? you have mentioned target folder and the classpath files, and it should work for both.